# OpenCL 1.2 Passing images to kernel

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I want to pass an image to a kernel and then render the output with OpenGL. Unfortunately, can't find a relevant example on this online anywhere and books I have seen use OpenCL 1.1. Here is how I am trying to do that:

```
    cl_kernel kernel;                   // compute kernel
    // Connect to a compute device
    //
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);


    // Create a compute context
    //
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);


    // Create a command commands
    //
    commands = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);


    // Create the compute program from the source buffer
    //
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &err);

    // Build the program executable
    //
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
    //
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "gaussian_filter", &err);
    if (!kernel || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t static width = 800;
    size_t static height = 800;
    char *buffer = new char[width * height * 4](); //create an empty array of bytes

    static const cl_image_format format = { CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT };
    cl_mem inputImage = clCreateImage2D(context,
                                         CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, &format,
                                         width, height, 0,
                                         buffer,
                                         &err); //deprecated


    cl_mem outputImage = clCreateFromGLTexture(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,texture,NULL);

    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error creating CL image object");
        return 0;
    }

    cl_sampler sampler = clCreateSampler(context,
                              CL_TRUE, // Non-normalized coordinates
                              CL_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
                              CL_FILTER_NEAREST,
                              &err);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error creating CL sampler object");
        return 1;
    }


    // Write our data set into the input array in device memory
    //

    // Set the arguments to our compute kernel
    //
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), inputImage);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), *outputImage);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_sampler), &sampler);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_int), &width);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_int), &height);

    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to set kernel arguments! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }
```

But this gives me a EXC_BAD_ACESS error on `err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), inputImage);`
Here is my kernel. It just outpus a white pixel:

```
__kernel void gaussian_filter(__read_only image2d_t srcImg,
                              __write_only image2d_t dstImg,
                              sampler_t sampler,
                              int width, int height)
{
    // Gaussian Kernel is:
    // 1 2 1
    // 2 4 2
    // 1 2 1
    float kernelWeights[9] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f,
        2.0f, 4.0f, 2.0f,
        1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };
    int2 startImageCoord = (int2) (get_global_id(0) - 1,
                                   get_global_id(1) - 1);
    int2 endImageCoord = (int2) (get_global_id(0) + 1,
                                 get_global_id(1) + 1);
    int2 outImageCoord = (int2) (get_global_id(0),
                                 get_global_id(1));
    if (outImageCoord.x < width && outImageCoord.y < height)
    {
        float4 outColor = (float4)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Write the output value to image
        write_imagef(dstImg, outImageCoord, outColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&inputImage);`?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelNastenko (although you can skip the `(void*)`). Also, `*outputImage` should be `&outputImage`.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko, you are absolutely right. That fixed it! Thank you!